# Can not open a video file in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, video, ffmpeg

I have a video file that encoded in h264 and save in mkv format (*.mkv). 
I can pen file in VLC and play it, but I want to open it in OpenCV and extract each frame of the video.

I have this code:

```
std::string fileName = "D:/Temp/video.mkv";

cv::VideoCapture capture(fileName);
capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC, CV_FOURCC('H', '2', '6', '4'));
if (!capture.isOpened())
{
    //error!
    std::cout << "Can not load video";
}
else
{
    double prevtimestamp = 0;
    cv::Mat frame;

    while (1)
    {
        capture.grab();
        double timestamp = capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC);

    }
}
```

when I run this code, I am getting message that the file can not be open.

My questions:

1. Is there anything wrong with this code?
2. Do I need FFMPEG on the path so OpenCV can open h264 videos?
3. How can I get more information why OpenCV can not open the file?

Comment: You don't have to set `FOURCC` of the input video capture. Yes, the ffmpeg DLL should be in the system PATH.

Comment: @sgarizvi I removed that code and also placed opencv_ffmpeg_64.dll next to running application, but still getting the same error. How can I get detail of error from OpenCV?

Comment: This might be related to your OpenCV build. Did you have x264 codec libraries and ffmpeg while compiling OpenCV? Check your root CMakeLists.txt options, for example `OCV_OPTION(WITH_FFMPEG`. Your code works on my PC, I use OpenCV3.3.0 checkout from [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git)

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].